# RAMDisk option in NTLDR

Tags: ramdisk, ntldr

While experimenting for [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/82655/multiple-nt52-entries-in-bootmgr/82656#82656), I came accross the following messages in NTLDR:

- Windows could not start due to an error while booting from a RAMDISK.
- The RAMDISK options specified in boot.ini are invalid.
- Windows failed to build a bootable RAMDISK image.
- Windows failed to open the RAMDISK image.

Does this mean that Windows XP includes a RAMDisk?  Does anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that Windows XP
>   includes a RAMDisk?

Yes, it's a relic from the olden days.

> Does anyone know how to use it?

**[You can use the dos based ramdrive.sys in Win XP by following these steps.](http://www.hardwareanalysis.com/content/topic/7663/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can set ramdisk options for booting from [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment). ntldr is used to boot a full Windows installation as well as WinPE 1.0 (used with XP) over PXE, so it includes this functionality. It is not something that is used during a standard boot-up of an already installed operating system